# How can I close popup from background?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I know we can close a popup using `window.close()` from popup.

But is there any way to close the popup from the background page in a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with [`chrome.extension.getViews`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews):

```
var windows = chrome.extension.getViews({type: "popup"});
if (windows.length) {
  windows[0].close(); // Normally, there shouldn't be more than 1 popup 
} else {
  console.log("There was no popup to close");
}
```